# How to find from where a XamlObjectWriterException is coming?

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, styles, resourcedictionary

I have a resource dictionary with 12.000 lines.

If I activate `First Chance Exceptions` I get some `XamlObjectWriterException` with an inner of type `NotSupportedException` claiming that it cannot create a `DependencyProperty` from text 'Padding' or 'Foreground'.

Line number and position are set to 0 so I don't know where the error is coming. The exceptions are coming from the loading of the resource dictionary on app startup, before using the styles anywhere.

Is there a way to find what style is (are) the offending ones?

[image]

Comment: Can you read line per line? If yes try a loop and count the rows so you can find the error line

Comment: I don't know how to read it line by line, I just added the ResourceDictionary and the WPF infrastructure is the one reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find what style is (are) the offending ones?

I am afraid the XAML processor doesn't give this detailed information. But at least it gives you a clue.

Search for all places where you set the `Foreground` property and comment them out one by one and compile and run until you have narrowed down the issue. I am afraid there is no easier way unless you are able to guess in which resource the error may be.